# Dynamic Sheet naming and copying data

Tags: vba, excel

I have been a silent reader on here for a few months but have been struggling with this code for a week now, so thought i would see if anyone can help.

I have a worksheet where sheet 1 contains information for users to input data.
Column A ask a question, column C is where the user will type in an answer.
Row 4 asks how many configurations there will be. depending on what number they input depends on how many cells light up to the right ie if 1 then D4 goes yellow, if 2 then D4 and E4 go yellow (using conditional formatting) 
The user will then enter the title into the highlighted cell (D4,E4 ,F4 etc)
I want to create a new sheet at the end of the sheet for each configuration. 
then NAME the new sheet by the text entered in D4, E4 etc.

the code I have so far is:

```
 Option Explicit

Sub InsertSupplierSheet()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tmpSht As Worksheet
Dim Lastcol As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim DESCRANGE As Range

'~~> Change Sheet1 to the sheet which has all the data
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

With ws
    Lastcol = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    If Lastcol < 4 Then Exit Sub

    For i = 3 To Lastcol
        If DoesSheetExist(ActiveSheet.Cells(4 & i).Value) Then
            Set tmpSht = ActiveSheet.Cells(4 & i).Value
        Else
            Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            Set tmpSht = ActiveSheet
            tmpSht.Name = "NEWSHEET"


        End If

        .Rows("1:3").Copy tmpSht.Rows(1)

        For j = 1 To 4
            tmpSht.Columns(j).ColumnWidth = .Columns(j).ColumnWidth
        Next j

        .Rows(i).Copy tmpSht.Rows(4)
    Next
End With
End Sub

Function DoesSheetExist(Sht As String) As Boolean
Dim ws As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Set ws = Sheets(ws)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not ws Is Nothing Then DoesSheetExist = True
End Function
```

I put in "NEWSHEET" to see if even creates a new sheet, but it still fails. I just cant see where I am going wrong.

Any help /advise  is welcomed.

EDIT .

I cant work out why though. 
The last col will be  H4 so lastcol would be "8" . 
Then for i = 4 to 8 run the loop. there are descriptions in each of the cells in row 4 so i don't see why it would work for 2 instantness and then fail ?

I dont know if this would make it easier but I have the number of sheets i want to create in cell C4 so i could use this rather than looking up populated cells. so if C4 is 2 then I want to add 2 sheets named as the content of  D4, E4. if C4 is 3 then I want to add 3 sheets names as content of D3,E3,F3. Am I making this harder than I need too ?

UPDATE 
I figured out the copying over of info is affecting this loop. and amended the code to this.

```
Sub InsertSupplierSheet()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tmpSht As Worksheet
Dim Lastcol As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim DESCRANGE As Range
Dim sShtName As String 'Dimension sheet name variable

'~~> Change Sheet1 to the sheet which has all the data
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

With ws
Lastcol = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

If Lastcol < 4 Then Exit Sub

For i = 4 To Lastcol
    sShtName = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, i).Value2 'Set sShtName to cell value     within loop
If DoesSheetExist(sShtName) Then 'Use sShtName to call "Exists" function
    Set tmpSht = Sheets(sShtName)
Else
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Set tmpSht = ActiveSheet
    tmpSht.Name = sShtName 'Change name to sShtName
End If

    .Rows("1:3").Copy tmpSht.Rows(1)


    .Rows(13).Copy tmpSht.Rows(4)
Next
End With
End Sub

Function DoesSheetExist(Sht As String) As Boolean
Dim ws As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Set ws = Sheets(Sht)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not ws Is Nothing Then DoesSheetExist = True
End Function
```

this is doing what i want it to do with a couple of small exceptions. 
the Sheets are being named by the cells in D1 , then E13,F13,G13,H13 So i need to figure out where that info is coming from. 
the final bit is that due to my conditional formatting in the First sheet, I am getting text on black backgrounds in the copy cells, but that is the very least of my worries !
UPDATE 
Found the error -

```
    sShtName = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, i).Value2
```

should be

```
    sShtName = Worksheets(1).Cells(4, i).Value2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling your cells incorrectly. Use `(4, i)` instead of `(4 & i)`.

The way you were calling it concatenated it to `43`, which resulted in you checking cell AQ1 (AQ being the 43rd column) for the sheet reference.

Edit: I just walked through it a bit and found a couple of other errors. You need to set the sheet name to `sht` in your 'exists' function, and I'm assuming you want to set `tmpSht` to a sheet, so you need to encase it in `sheets()`. Try this:

```
Sub InsertSupplierSheet()

Dim ws As Worksheet 
Dim tmpSht As Worksheet
Dim Lastcol As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim DESCRANGE As Range
Dim sShtName As String 'Dimension sheet name variable

'~~> Change Sheet1 to the sheet which has all the data
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

With ws
Lastcol = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

If Lastcol < 4 Then Exit Sub

For i = 4 To Lastcol
    sShtName = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, i).Value2 'Set sShtName to cell value within loop
    If DoesSheetExist(sShtName) Then 'Use sShtName to call "Exists" function
        Set tmpSht = Sheets(sShtName)
    Else
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Set tmpSht = ActiveSheet
        tmpSht.Name = sShtName 'Change name to sShtName
    End If

    .Rows("1:3").Copy tmpSht.Rows(1)

    For j = 1 To 4
        tmpSht.Columns(j).ColumnWidth = .Columns(j).ColumnWidth
    Next j

    .Rows(i).Copy tmpSht.Rows(4)
Next
End With
End Sub

Function DoesSheetExist(Sht As String) As Boolean
Dim ws As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Set ws = Sheets(Sht)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not ws Is Nothing Then DoesSheetExist = True
End Function
```

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please mark it as the accepted answer. If not, let me know how I can help more.

Comment: HI JMcD This is a great help. I now have new sheet being created with information being copied over. Now i need to work out How to rename the sheet with the info in cell D4 and the next one with info in E4  etc..

Comment: It'll probably help if you set the name to a variable because you'll be using it in multiple places. I'll update the code example above to show what I mean.

Comment: I just updated it, and added comments to show how to do that. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Hi @JMcD This was more promising, I am testing the sheet with 5 descriptions (the maximum i am allowing for this sheet) The first 2 work new sheet named as desc 2, desc 3 as cells  D4, E4, then it adds the sheet "sheet6" and Fails. Runtime error 1004 Method'name of object'_worksheet'failed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the new sheet and then setting the activesheet to the tmpsht you could use a shorter way (see below). And why did you set the ws if you don't use it....

```
Sub InsertSupplierSheet()

    Dim ws As Worksheet 
    Dim tmpSht As Worksheet
    Dim Lastcol As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim DESCRANGE As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    With ws
        Lastcol = .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        If (Lastcol < 4) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        For i = 4 To Lastcol
            If (DoesSheetExist(.Cells(4, i).Value2) = True) Then
                Set tmpSht = Sheets(.Cells(4, i).Value)
            Else
                Set tmpSht = Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                tmpSht.Name = "NEWSHEET"
            End If

            .Rows("1:3").Copy tmpSht.Rows(1)

            For j = 1 To 4
                tmpSht.Columns(j).ColumnWidth = .Columns(j).ColumnWidth
            Next j

            .Rows(i).Copy tmpSht.Rows(4)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub


Function DoesSheetExist(Sht As String) As Boolean

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Sheets(Sht)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not ws Is Nothing Then
        DoesSheetExist = True
    Else
        DoesSheetExist = False
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your halp, but I cant get this to work, I have a syntex error on the line.  Set tmpSht = Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

Comment: Ok, then I guess that doesn't work. You can use your code for that part so "sheets.add after:=Sheets(sheets.count)" and then "set tmpSht = ActiveSheet" "tmpSht.Name = (.Cells(4, i).Value)"

Answer (score 0):

This was my final code. There were a few tweaks, Firstly I added a formula in row 6 to shorten the name of row 4 to a 10 character name as I found the tab names were too long (hence the code for the naming refers to row 6. I also added some custom text to add into each sheet and some formatting

```
Option Explicit


Sub InsertSupplierSheet()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tmpSht As Worksheet
Dim Lastcol As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim DESCRANGE As Range
Dim sShtName As String 'Dimension sheet name variable

'~~> Change Sheet1 to the sheet which has all the data
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

With ws

Lastcol = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' work         with the template sheet

If Lastcol = 3 Then Exit Sub 'repeat these steps from the first config to the last

For i = 4 To Lastcol

sShtName = Worksheets(1).Cells(6, i).Value2 'Set sShtName to cell value within loop
If DoesSheetExist(sShtName) Then 'Use sShtName to call "Exists" function
   Set tmpSht = Sheets(sShtName)
Else
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Set tmpSht = ActiveSheet
    tmpSht.Name = sShtName 'Change name to sShtName tmpSht.Name = sShtName
End If

.Rows("1:3").Copy tmpSht.Rows(1) ' Format the cell width in the new sheet
.Rows(13).Copy tmpSht.Rows(4)
 tmpSht.Range("A1").Value = Worksheets(1).Cells(4, i).Value2
 Range("A1").ColumnWidth = 30
 Range("B1").ColumnWidth = 0
 Range("C1").ColumnWidth = 30
 Range("D1:K1").ColumnWidth = 10
 Range("D4:J4").Font.Color = vbWhite ' format the colour of the text in the new sheet
 Range("C1") = " "    ' Negate info in cell C1

 With Range("A1:M5") ' add borders

'Clear existing
.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone

'Apply new borders
.BorderAround xlContinuous
.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous

End With
 With Range("A1:C4") ' set colours for the new sheet
  .Font.Color = vbBlack
  .Interior.Color = vbWhite

 End With
 Range("D4:J4").Font.Color = vbWhite ' set colour of the numbers to white to show on black background
 Range("A5") = "Unit cost in " & Worksheets(1).Cells(17, 3).Value2
 Range("A6") = "CUSTOM TEXT ONE."
 Range("A7") = "NOTE if quantity " & Range("D4").Value2 + 5 & " is ordered then total cost will be your unit cost for " & Range("D4").Value2 & " multiplied by " & Range("D4").Value2 + 5 & " .This applies up to the quantity of " & Range("E4").Value2 - 1
 Range("A8") = "CUSTOM TEXT 2"


Next i
End With
End Sub

Function DoesSheetExist(Sht As String) As Boolean
Dim ws As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Set ws = Sheets(Sht)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not ws Is Nothing Then DoesSheetExist = True
End Function
```